# Stripe avoid paymentintent with status 'Incomplete'

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe's 'Payment' element for creating paymentintent and card charges, Using PHP, HTML & JS.
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element

a) As soon as i load the payment page, Stripe generates a paymentintent with status 'Incomplete'.
b) After i enter Credit Card details and hit 'pay', Stripe again issues a second paymentintent with status accordingly (say 'Succeeded')

The result is, that my Dashboard is now full of unnecessary records

This is, because i initialize the `$paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create` as soon as the page loads.
I understand that this is Stripe default behaviour, because at that moment, no payment_method is attached yet.

My question is: How is this resolved best, to avoid such 'Incomplete' records?

- Maybe attach an object and fire the paymentintent creation only when
  that object is present?
- Or onclick of the 'pay' button..awaiting paymentintent, confirm presence and then submit the form?
- Or retrieve that 1st paymentintent, store it and then update with
  form submission?

[image]

create.php

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

try {

    // retrieve JSON from POST body
    $jsonStr = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);

    // Create a PaymentIntent with amount and currency
    $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
        'amount' => 1000,
        'currency' => 'eur',
        'receipt_email' => 'whatever@mail.com',
        'automatic_payment_methods' => ['enabled' => true,],
        'description' => 'Reservation Dimi123 / Name: John Doe',
        'metadata' => ['order_id' => '12345']
    ]);
 
    $output = [
        'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
    ];

    echo json_encode($output);
} catch (Error $e) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

script.js

```js
const stripe = Stripe("pk_test_..");

let elements;

initialize();
checkStatus();

document
  .querySelector("#payment-form")
  .addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

// Fetches a payment intent and captures the client secret
async function initialize() {
  const { clientSecret } = await fetch("../create.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  }).then((r) => r.json());

  elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret });

  const paymentElement = elements.create("payment");
  paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
}

async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);

  const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      return_url: "https://localhost/stripe/prebuilt-checkout-custom-flow/public/checkout.html",
    },
  });

  if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
    showMessage(error.message);
  } else {
    showMessage("An unexpected error occurred.");
  }

  setLoading(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to Avoid Incomplete Payment Intents? You don't.

This is how the system is designed to function since you need the `client_secret` from the Payment Intent (or Setup Intent) to render the Payment Element.  There is no negative impact to your account.

You should feel comfortable ignoring them.  You can adjust the filters in your Payments tab to not see them.  They aren't a great metric of individual customers coming to your payment interface and navigating away since any user refreshing their browser would trigger a new one.

#### Update 3/26/2024

There is now a canonical flow that will allow you to defer the creation of the Payment Intent until *after* you collect payment method details.  This can allow you to avoid creating Payment Intents until the user has provided their payment method information.  You can find that integration documentation [here](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred)

Comment: but it works when the element is 'card' and not 'payment'
https://github.com/stripe-archive/accept-a-card-payment/tree/master/without-webhooks/server/php/public
It can't be that a paymentintent can't be requested 'when needed' .. e.g. when 'fetch' would be placed on submit etc
I just can't figure out the proper way.
Personally, i don't mind about these 'incomplete' entries, but my clients will.. because they have to charge THEIR clients

Comment: Ah that is how the old Card Element worked.  The Payment Element was designed differently.  The new flow I just updated the answer with includes the link to a new integration that allows the same thing.